# Why is my PyCharm debug button greyed out?

Tags: pycharm

I use PyCharm for development for Google App Engine. Now I'm trying it with Ubuntu  Linux and I installed it and run it but the buttons to the upper right are greyed out and I don't know what to do about it. What can be done to run the project?[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to go to Run | Edit Configurations... and create a Google App Engine run configuration for your project.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the default configurations are not what you need. You have to literally press the plus sign button, and then choose python. When I read this answer, I was confused because I thought I just needed to configure the default python configuration, but that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, you need:
- a configuration (Run, Debug..., Edit Configurations...)
- the indexing has to be finished

I had the latter in a big project and couldn't figure out why debugging was not possible :p
Hope it helps someone else. This was the first result for me on google.