# Can't run file in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

In PyCharm run button is Disable and I can't run File.

[image: run button is Disable]

Comment: It says "Updating skeletons" at the bottom. Did the run button turn green when that finished?

Comment: You need to have a run configuration active. You get one created automatically when you run the file. Right-click the mouse anywhere inside the code area and choose `Run file...`

Comment: Also: [Why is my PyCharm debug button greyed out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813488/why-is-my-pycharm-debug-button-greyed-out)

Comment: @DavidBuck Hi , Yes it's  Finish

Comment: @Tomerikoo Hi , Thanks for your answer ,thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The charlesdk's answer is correct, but i would like to add something. 
If you want to create a custom PyCharm configuration you can click on "Add Configuration" button present at the top-right corner of the window.

Here, clicking on plus symbol (+) you can add a Python configuration to run your He.py file. At this point, the run button will be enabled and you can just click on that button to run the program.

Answer (score 0):

Try to right-click on the `He.py` tab, you should be able to see the run button. Click it to run the file.